# Install OpenShift command line interface in Windows

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I am installing OpenShift command line interface (CLI) for window 7 32bit from the [documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/cli_reference/get_started_cli.html#installing-the-cli):

But error occur:

> [Window Title]
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\oc_2\oc.exe
>
> The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows
>   you're running. Check your computer's system information to see
>   whether you need an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the
>   program, and then contact the software publisher.

What ma I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows version of the `oc` binary is 64 bit only. There are no 32 bit versions available for current releases of OpenShift.

Comment: Oh. Thank you very much.